# type guard on member of class

Tags: typescript

I feel like there may be some documentation I'm missing here, but basically what I'm trying to do is something like the following:

```js
class Agent {
  public world: World | undefined;
  //...
  checkWorld(): this.world is World {
    return this.world !== undefined;
  }
}
```

Such that in a different function I could do something along the lines of the following:

```
const agent = new Agent();
if(!agent.checkWorld()) {
  throw new Error("No world assigned to agent");
} 
// Handle the agent as appropriate, knowing the world exists
```

However, typescript is certainly not happy with the `checkWorld(): this.world is World` syntax, saying 'All declarations of 'world' must have identical modifiers. My current solution is simply

```
if(agent.world === undefined) {
  throw new Error("No world assigned to agent");
}
agent.world = agent.world as World;
// Handle the agent as appropriate, knowing the world exists
```

However, this seems less than ideal. It's certainly possible this is something that I can't implicitly handle in typescript.

Of course, something like the following works:

```
checkWorld(w: World | undefined): w is World {
  return w !== undefined;
}
//...
if(!checkWorld(agent.world)) {
  throw new Error('No world assigned to agent');
}
```

But typescript isn't automatically acknowledging that agent.world isn't undefined past that point, so something like `agent.world = agent.world as World` is still necessary.

EDIT: I know this example is somewhat contrived, because the union type is only World or undefined, but in the actual code I have a host of different world types, and would like to do a type check if it's a specific type of world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option. Rather than trying to narrow the type on `this.world`, narrow it on `this`:

```
class Agent {
  public world: World | undefined;
  //...
  checkWorld(): this is { world: World } {
    return this.world !== undefined;
  }
}

const agent = new Agent();
if(!agent.checkWorld()) {
  throw new Error("No world assigned to agent");
} 
// At this point, agent's type is Agent & { world: World }
// You can write code knowing agent.world exists.
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA6g9gJwDYBMoF4oHIBmc5YDcAUMQMZICGAztVAIIDmEAdsFAN7FRRgCuAIyQBLMlADuiVAC5YUtAB8ofFigg5hLCChI8A9HoB0x7lDIALCGQDW8ZCgAUASlnBzwuh84T5su6igAX05THgQIYD4EFig3D0NJeygAQnRMFTUNLR1TQOI88jgWanZKZjYMKC1xBnLgZxJhHAdkstZgQwsrW3lnJxCeNwQ4GuqoAFEEYYQHACIAOTgfJJpqYUZs2KW2tlmnEmDC4rgkCEMkOEYHHY7E1ENgOAAZEYgEAGEaCD7CKAMoRZQN7TAA0UAEVkofGo0DcsPA0HMNHBEFYVUoU1eKCAA)

Comment: This is exactly the sort of solution I was looking for!